# Wordpress post name permalink with nginx show 404 error

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, permalinks

I have a problem with wordpress permalinks and nginx.
For example i have a post with id = 29 and name=stars.
When I access to my post at www.domaine.com/?p=29 using simple permalink it works, but when I access the same post using post name as permalink at www.domaine.com/stars I get an error 404 "Object not found".
I tried to check the existance of files using this directive :

```
try_files $uri $uri / /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
```

also i tried to use this one :

```
try_files $uri $uri / /index.php?$args;
```

But nothing work.

Plugins that i use: Hide My WP plugin, AMP, Yoast SEO.

How can i resolve this ?

Comment: check .htaccess in your root directory and its permission as well.

Comment: I'm using nginx. I don't have .htaccess file

Comment: Your `try_files` statement has spurious spaces in it. Have you seen [this recipe](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/wordpress/)? You should include your `nginx` configuration (specifically the `server` block) in your question.

Comment: I don't have a server block, I have a directory in which I can find the files to write my own rules on each environment (prod and dev). also, there is no need to set the block server {} (this is in any case forbidden by nginx i think), because this file, is included in the main block {} of my site. In particular, the server_name without and with www are already defined, so i need just to add my directives.

Comment: Please check this Wordpress codex if it helps: https://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx

Answer (score 0):

Altering the line to this Solved my permalink issue

```
 try_files /maintenance.html $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
```